# Weights Variable modification after creation and still want to train it in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to reassign weights with different values than the initialized and still train it successfully?

For ex:

```
Weights= tf.Variable(shape, zeros(), name="weights")
update_weights = weights + steps * bytes
Weights = Weights.assign(update_weights)
```

But I get the following error when I train it using AdamOptimizer:

```
Trying to optimize unsupported type <tf.Tensor 'conv_1/Assign:0' shape=(5, 5, 1, 30) dtype=float32_ref>
```

To convert tensor to variable suitable for minimize() of Adam optimizer: used this:

```
 q_weights = tf.Variable(q_weights.assign(weights))
```

But got the following error!

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input 0 of node conv_2/Variable/conv_2/Assign_conv_2/Variable_0 was passed float from conv_2/Variable/cond/Merge:0 incompatible with expected float_ref.
```

Full flow of code attached:

```
Weights= tf.Variable(shape, zeros(), name="weights")
update_weights = weights + steps * bytes
Weights = Weights.assign(update_weights)

conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, Weights, ...)
act = tf.nn.relu(...)

tf.add_to_collection('train_params, Weights)

do dot ....
tf.add_to_collection('train_params, Weights)


do all remaining layers.....
tf.add_to_collection('train_params, Weights)

do logits 
tf.add_to_collection('train_params, Weights)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels, logits)

back_prop = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LR).minimize(loss, var_list = tf.get_collection('train_params')

repeat for every iteration
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error occurred because `tf.assign` returned a `tf.Tensor`, not a `tf.Variable`. Would you update the `Weights` by `steps*bytes` at each iteration? If so, just use `update_weights` in the following calculations, given the gradient is the same for `Weights` and `updated_weights`. If not, initialize `Weights` as `steps*bytes` would be the best option. Otherwise, please try put the rest graph definition under `with tf.control_dependencies(tf.assign(Weights, update_weights)):`.

Comment: Put your entire code, otherwise it is difficult to understand where your error came from. It seems you are minimizing directly the `assign` operation. You should simply work with the initial `Weights` object and simply run `Weights.assign(update_weights)` when you want to assign it.

Comment: @Richard_wth I am not able to directly use updated_weights. It throws the error above. Because adam;optimizer would only accept a variable to make gradient updates. Is there a way to convert tensor to a trainable variable i.e) to treat update_weights as a variable and update it during every iteration of training?

Comment: @GiuseppeMarra update_Weights is not w.r.t gradients from Adamoptimizer. I would want to treat update_weights as the initial weight values and apply adamoptimizer's gradient updates over it during each iteration. But the type doesn't match the one expected by adam during the minimize function. Is it a way to use updated_weights for minimize() of Adam?

Comment: @mkar I am afraid that converting `Tensor` to `Variable` is impossible. When I said "using `update_weights` in following calculations", I mean, for example, you may use `update_weights` to do convolutions. I did not mean using it in Adam update as well...Perhaps it is best, as GiuseppeMarra said, that you provide some code so that we would know exactly what you wanna do.  :)

Comment: @Richard_wth Hello Richard, Thanks. I have attached the code flow and its usage. Let me know if that's enough to clarify my doubts.

Comment: @mkar Thanks for posting your code. However, I still do not understand the logic behind so many `tf.add_to_collection('train_params, Weights)`. Do you want to share/link the weights of many convolution layers in some manner?

Comment: @Richard_wth I resolved the issue by providing the updated weights during initialization. Thanks a lot for your help,.

Answer (score 0):

Just put some dependency on your Graph, since you want to tell "Before starting your computation update the weights like this" which gets translated into:

```
Weights= tf.Variable(shape, zeros(), name="weights")
update_weights = tf.assign(Weights,  Weights + steps * bytes)
with tf.control_dependencies([update_weights]):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, Weights, ...)
    etc. etc.
```

Comment: I resolved the issue by providing the updated weights during initialization. Thanks a lot for your help,.